# React Native Problem: My Button isn't going bigger in the ScrolView

Tags: javascript, react-native

I tried to restart the app, but the result is the same.
I am using the "Expo Go" app in my phone, i dont have a picture but it shows the Text: "TESTE" and a normal button with the title:"BOTÃO".

The entire code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Alert, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
render(){

    return(
      <View style={{
        alignItems:'center',
      }}> 
        
          <Text style={estilo.fonte}>TESTE</Text>
```

> Here is the ScrollView With the Button:

```
            <ScrollView>

              <Button
                title='Botão'
                style={{width:'50%'}}
              />
    
            </ScrollView>**
    
      </View>

)};
}

const estilo = StyleSheet.create({

fonte:{
marginTop:'10%',
fontSize:20,
backgroundColor:'rgb(240,240,240)',
borderRadius:50,
width:300,
textAlign:'center',
fontWeight:'bold'
}

});

I want the button with 50% of width
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.